# Target ID for Div not propagating

Tags: javascript, jquery, target

With a table inside a div, I thought the target ID would propagate up when I try to find what target triggered the click event. Instead nothing is returned when I click inside the table. I would like to know the id of the div containing the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/UWm46/

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
alert("Target ID: " + event.target.id);   
});

<div id='box3'>
box 3
<table><tr><td>table 3</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be working on jsfiddle u provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use `.closest()`.

```
$(event.target).closest('div').attr('id');
```

Here is an demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UWm46/3/

Answer (score 1):

When you click the "table 3" text, the target is the `td`, and the `td` doesn't have an ID.

to get the closest ancestor with an id, you could use this:

http://jsfiddle.net/g6S65/

```
$(event.target).closest('[id]').attr('id')
```